# How to avoid v-html from changing content on website?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a code editor in `vue`.
I used `v-html` to render the html, css and js.

Here is some code:

```
<template>
  <div class="grid">
    <div id="html" class="grid-cell">
      <textarea v-model="htmlCode" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <div class="title">This is a cell</div>
    </div>
    <div id="css" class="grid-cell">
      <textarea v-model="cssCode" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <div class="title">This is a cell</div>
    </div>
    <div id="js" class="grid-cell">
      <textarea v-model="jsCode" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <div class="title">This is a cell</div>
    </div>
    <div id="preview" class="grid-cell">
      <div
        v-html="
          htmlCode +
          styleBegin +
          cssCode +
          stylEend +
          scriptBegin +
          jsCode +
          scriptEnd
        "
      ></div>
      <div class="title">This is a cell</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "CodeEditor",
  methods: {},
  data() {
    return {
      htmlCode: "<h1>hi</h1>",
      cssCode: "",
      jsCode: "",
      styleBegin: "<style>",
      styleEnd: "</style>",
      scriptBegin: "<script>",
      scriptEnd: "</"+"script>"
    };
  },
  computed: {},
};
</script>
```

The problem that I have, is that when a user inputs something in the code editor, it can affect the website itself (my website)

If anyone knows a solution, I would highly appreciate it, thanks!

Comment: You might consider putting the user's code in an iframe, instead, so it's sandboxed off from the rest of the page.

Comment: thanks, but could you please show a small example, because don't completely understand what you mean?

Comment: @EmielVandeVeire [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Ok, but could you show an example of how I should implement this in my code, because there is no source that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `iframe` and it's [**`srcdoc`** attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_srcdoc.asp), as follow:

```html
<iframe :srcdoc="
   htmlCode + 
   styleBegin + 
   cssCode + 
   stylEend + 
   scriptBegin + 
   jsCode + 
   scriptEnd"></iframe>
```